# Removing an appended parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list maker that appends items but also appends a trash can item to each of the list items which is made. I have a function on the trash can that should remove the parent element when it is clicked but it doesn't work.

Here is a simple version of what I'm trying to do

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfLLmwbg/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#contain').append('<div class="div"></div>').append('<div class="nested"></div>');
});

$('.nested').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

How can I remove the parent element of only the nested div that is clicked?

Comment: Your `nested` is not inside the `div` that you appended first. They're siblings. So the parent of `nested` is the `#contain` element.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because you're calling an event on dynamically appended element.

```
$('body').on('click', '.nested', function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Also we can use `$('#contain')` instead of `$('body')` as well.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
 $('#contain').append('<div class="div"></div>').append('<div class="nested"></div>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.nested', function() {
 $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.nested {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add
</button>

<div id="contain">
</div>
```

Comment: if he wants to remove just one at a time your button on click should be `$('#contain').append('<div class="div"></div>');
  $('#contain div:last').append('<div class="nested"></div>');`

Comment: `.appendTo()` would be cleaner. `$('<div class="div"></div>').appendTo("#contain").append('<div class="nested"></div>')`

Comment: you could still attach the `.on()` to `('#contain')` instead of `$('body')` to keep the scope simpler

Comment: @Shniper : Glad to see that it helped you, even you can go the official document of http://api.jquery.com/on/ and get the details.. And don't forget to accept the answer that will encourage the people to use this solution.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$('#contain').on('click', '.nested', function(){

});
```

you have to listen to clicks on the container for appended elements, since they're not in the DOM when the page is loaded

Comment: This answer is better since the delegate is closer to the intended targets.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. As the others have mentioned, you're binding your `.nested` click
   event *before* your element is created, meaning it won't have the
   event handler attached. As the others mentioned, something like `$("#contain").on("click", ".nested", function() {})` will fix the issue
2. `$.append` returns the element you are *appending to* not the element *being appended* so your `.nested` is nested under the `$("#contain")`. This means the `$(this).parent()` is actually returning the `#contain` element. A fix for the issue is

   ```
   $("<div class='nested' />").appendTo($("<div class='div' />").appendTo("#contain"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
$('.nested').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**To:**

```
$(document).on("click",".nested",function(){

    $(this).parent().remove();

})
```